# Grails 2.2.3 - How to create a new HTTP Session?

Tags: grails, httpsession

I'm creating a web project where I have to use my own authentication implementation (yes, I'm totally aware of the fact that it's not recommended but I have to do it this way...). Now, I want to create a new `HttpSession` for the logged in user once the authentication was successful but I can't find any source where something like this is done without the Spring Security Plugin in the back... what's the magic behind creating a new HttpSession for a user?

So, what I want to achieve is the following scenario

Login Page (user has already a session with a session id) --> User logs in --> check login credentials and create a new session with a new session id if the login was successful --> work with the new session for the logged in user.

I hope someone can help me with this as I really need it ;)

Comment: Not sure if you really want this or not but you can set userId in the session as: session["id"] = <userId>

and can perform a check on the session on the filters, and exclude login controller, or just the auth action(If you have these names for login->auth action)

Comment: @SaurabhDixit thanks for the idea, but I think I can't use it as I create a user object per session and destroy the session on logout, but I want to be able to let the user start another application and work with a different session so that I can create a new user for the then started application... hope this sounds not too weird, but it's basically what I try to implement ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller, can't you do something like

```
// get rid of any existing session
session().invalidate()
// create a new session
request.session(true)
```

( I haven't checked the syntax for this ..... and I usually work in Java so it may well be wrong, but you get the drift )

Comment: it works - thanks a lot! now there's just one problem left: I create a session scoped service per user which, but if I call `.invalidate` either on the injected `session` object or on the `request.session` object it seems that my service gets also destroyed... seems like I have to move that things out of my service class into another session scoped bean or something like that...

Comment: I don't think you should think of the injected session and request.session as being different things. What the code above does is to destroy one session and create a new one. From your response to @SaurabhDixi 'd comment above, i think you might be attempting to use the session in a way that it's not supposed to be used in. It's not usual to have two sessions running concurrently for the same user.